# Google Plus button not working in magento

Tags: javascript, json, magento, google-plus

I am trying to add google plus button on a site hosted on cloud.The URL of the cloud is http://145.56.183.76/magento/

This URL is publicy available.

I added the following code inside div tag in my page to render google plus button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>
```

I am able to see the google plus button when I run.I can login and add 1+.After this the google plus button turn into red exclaimation box...

When I tried it in firefox I could see in 
    POST:https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ there was 404 error thrown

```
 '[
      {
          "error": {
           "code": 400,
           "message": "Invalid Value",
           "data": [
            {
             "domain": "global",
             "reason": "invalid",
             "message": "Invalid Value"
            }
           ]
          },
          "id": "pos.plusones.insert"
         }
        ]'
```

If I am not wrong when we click on the button it actually pastes the URL in the google search and if its found it then updates it in google+.

I found a usefull link which talked about adding google plus magento extension.I have followed the steps but I am not able to view the google plus button.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/howto-google-1-extension-for-magento/

I know the problem is with the site url.Can some one help me in troubleshooting this issue.
Does it work only for public domains??If so is there an alternative to get it working with the above URL
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The +1 button will only work with public URLs.  From https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url:

> The +1 is a public action and must be performed on a public URL. If you attempt to +1 a URL that is not public, an error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you put Google API apart and use [**AddThis** API](http://www.addthis.com/get)

It does not only give you access to Google+ but as well more than 200 other services including [Facebook **Send**](http://www.addthis.com/help/third-party-buttons#.Tpfd5tLiE8k) and [Facebook **Like**](http://www.addthis.com/features/facebook-like-button#.Tpfdx9LiE8k)

see how the simple code from AddThis works on my **test page**: http://balexandre.com/addthis/

SignUp for free, and get your code to use, then, just add the buttons you want or use ``

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension if you want to add a google plus badge on your magento website

http://www.kdtips.co.nz/blog/2012/11/magento-google-plus-badge/